# Java SOAP client throwing exception "Call to a member function setValue() on a non-object"

Tags: java, eclipse, soap, soap-client

I created a web services client using Eclipse's built-in web service client creator (which I believe uses Apache Axis to generate the code?), and I'm running into an error that I can't seem to figure out. Here's what the exception says:

```
Exception in thread "main" AxisFault
 faultCode: {http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/}Server
 faultSubcode: 
 faultString: Call to a member function setValue() on a non-object
 faultActor: 
 faultNode: 
 faultDetail: 
    {http://xml.apache.org/axis/}stackTrace:Call to a member function setValue() on a non-object
    at org.apache.axis.message.SOAPFaultBuilder.createFault(SOAPFaultBuilder.java:222)
    at org.apache.axis.message.SOAPFaultBuilder.endElement(SOAPFaultBuilder.java:129)
    at org.apache.axis.encoding.DeserializationContext.endElement(DeserializationContext.java:1087)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.endElement(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanEndElement(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.next(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at javax.xml.parsers.SAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.axis.encoding.DeserializationContext.parse(DeserializationContext.java:227)
    at org.apache.axis.SOAPPart.getAsSOAPEnvelope(SOAPPart.java:696)
at org.apache.axis.Message.getSOAPEnvelope(Message.java:435)
    at org.apache.axis.handlers.soap.MustUnderstandChecker.invoke(MustUnderstandChecker.java:62)
    at org.apache.axis.client.AxisClient.invoke(AxisClient.java:206)
    at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invokeEngine(Call.java:2784)
    at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:2767)
    at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:2443)
    at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:2366)
    at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:1812)
    at com.symplicity.oppsplace_demo.ws.job_api_php.JobWebServiceBindingStub.processJob(JobWebServiceBindingStub.java:280)
    at com.symplicity.oppsplace_demo.ws.job_api_php.JobWebServicePortProxy.processJob(JobWebServicePortProxy.java:56)
    at main.OppsPlaceIntegration.main(OppsPlaceIntegration.java:37)
```

I'm using the API provided by [OppsPlace](https://oppsplace.com/job_integration) (a job posting site), and specifically I used this [WSDL](https://oppsplace-demo.symplicity.com/ws/job_api.php?wsdl) to build a client for their test environment.

Basically I create a Job object and a Contact object (generated classes from the WSDL) that are passed into the service along with my unique ID. It just bombs out with this same exception no matter what I try changing in my code.

As can be seen, the exception is happening pretty deep inside the Apache code, and for the life of me I can't figure out why. Any thoughts/ideas?

Comment: Funny that it mentions *'member function'* since Java officially has no functions, only methods. The error message looks like the PHP *'Call to a member function on a non-object'*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It mentions 'member function' while Java officially has no functions, only methods. The error message looks like the PHP 'Call to a member function on a non-object'. It is probably no coincidence that the OppsPlace API is implemented in PHP.

Congratulations, you ran into a bug in the API you are calling.

Comment: That makes complete sense. I'll follow up with the site about their API in that case. Thanks a bunch!

Comment: @nerdherd did you get any progress for sorting this type of error? calling it from JAVA(Android is my case.)